# Overload event handler in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got an event handler in JavaScript that I'd like to overload:

```
function overloadedHandler(event, myObject){
    if(event){
        var elem = event.currentTarget;
    } else {
        var elem = myObject.x;
    }
    //function logic
}

$('.mydiv').on('click', overloadedHandler);
```

If I want to call the `overloadedHandler` from another function (not as an event handler), what's the right way to do it?

1. `overloadedHandler(null, obj);`
2. `overloadedHandler(undefined, obj);`
3. `overloadedHandler(false, obj);`

P.S. I understand that I could put `//function logic` part in another function & call that when needed outside of an event handler, but I would like to know if there's anything wrong with the above approach?

Comment: 4. `overloadedHandler({currentTarget: obj.x});`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, but you could check inside the overloadedHandler for the type of the first argument using typeof.

Comment: @dfsq : Any of 1, 2 or 3 are wrong? With your method, if I'm using the event further down in the logic, I won't be able to distinguish if the call was from the event or otherwise. Granted that I didn't mention in my Q that I'd like to distinguish between the function calls

Comment: @buffer I wouldn't call it wrong. Clumsy, maybe. But this is up to your taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well indeed it seems a bit odd at first sight, but I would say that there is nothing wrong. It is basically equivalent to having an argument as optional, except that the event handling mechanism forces you to define the event as first argument so you cannot make it optional.

To make it as close as possible to an optional argument, I would set the event as `undefined` when calling it not as an event handler, since this is what the value would be if it was an optional argument. `null` would also be OK I guess, but I think `false` is semantically wrong: you want to say that there is no event, not that the event is false.

One way to make it maybe even cleaner would call it with an event argument made for the purpose. In your example, that would be:

```
overloadedHandler({currentTarget: obj.x}, obj);
```

Comment: Agreed. However in your example, if I'm using the event further down in the logic, I won't be able to distinguish if the call was from the event or otherwise. Granted that I didn't mention in my Q that I'd like to distinguish between the function calls.

Comment: I see, that makes the approach a bit "wronger" :) You usually want a function to do something defined that does not depend on the caller, otherwise it is less re-usable. But you can use the `undefined` approach, or: `{currentTarget: obj.x, doThatSpecificThingForNonHandler: true}`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `function ... does not depend on the caller`. Isn't function overloading all about re-using the code depending on who's calling it.

Comment: Technically overloading is changing the behaviour of a function depending on the signature (in JS: parameters). So in JS it translates to having optional parameters. Once a particular logic is defined, you don't want it to depend on who is calling, but rather on how it is called. Granted, the difference may be subtle if each caller has a unique way of calling, but thinking of it that way helps designing I think.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `null`, `undefined`, and `false` are all falsey, therefore `event` in `if (event)` will evaluate as false anytime those values are passed into that function via that parameter. There is nothing wrong with it any way you do it since it's simple evaluation. Unless you want to do different things with `null`, `undefined`, or `false` in the function (or there are extenuating circumstances like specific conventions, 'use strict' usages, etc), it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the following function just by setting first argument that something is false, as you pointed you can use any of those.

```
overloadedHandler(null, obj);
overloadedHandler(undefined, obj);
overloadedHandler(false, obj);
```

All of them would be fine. But I would use 'null', although it's subjective opinion.

Comment: Why is `null` better?